# How to override send_task BaseTask class?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I did some kind of mini framework to be able to catch connection errors with `celery` in case `rabbitmq` shuts down which handles errors in a more graceful way and it works pretty well except when using `send_task`.

Here is some code to clarify the idea:

```
class MyBaseTask(base_task.Task):
    """ Base Class to handle tasks from Me hohoho!"""
    abstract = True

    @classmethod
    def delay(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """Hook to catch connection errors"""
        try:
            return super(MyBaseTask, cls).apply_async(args, kwargs)
        except socket.error as e:
            cls._safe_failover()  # a function to handle this error
            cls.get_logger().error(str(e))
        except Exception as e:
            cls.get_logger().error("Uknown Error: %s" % str(e))
            raise  # normal exception
```

Now I subclass `MyBaseTask` class:

```
class MyL33tTask(MyBaseTask):
    name = 'task.my_leet_task'

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # yada yada
```

and it will execute the safe_failover function when a socket error happens (AKA, when `rabbitmq` is down). Sadly this doesn't happens when I use `send_task('task.my_leet_task')` since it uses some kind of proxy where `MyBaseTask` isn't loaded.

Is there an easy way to override `send_task` to use `MyBaseTask` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Has far has I understand the main utility of your logic is to make sure you are actually sending a task to the broker.

If my understanding is right than your approach is probably wrong and let me explain why.
When working with message passing the main advantages is that you can schedule tasks by passing a message to a broker, the method send_task in fact he doesn't know anything about the task itself it just compose a message well formatted for Celery and it send it to the configured broker (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-call-a-task-by-name).

Considering this, it becomes clear that exception catching of "failure of sending the message" should be handled where you call *send_message*.
The delay method could stay in that way but I would suggest to be more explicit and keep the catching logic where you actually call delay(), because again what to do if the task is not scheduled is not up to the task but up to the scheduler.